# what kind of views should I use?

Tags: 7, views

I am going to download the Views module for a Drupal 7 website I am creating, but there are 2 different versions: There is the alpha3, the development snapshot, and another one that doesn't have a name I can see (it is highlighted in green). Which these three versions should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main version of View,s 2.0 and 3.0.

Drupal 6 has support for both views

- 6.x-2.12 with Views 2
- 6.x-3.0-alpha3 with Views 3
- 6.x-3.x-dev with Views 3 and is under development

It is recommended to use 6.x-2.12

---

After clarifying about drupal7:

For Drupal 7 there is `Views 7.x-3.0-rc1` recommended.

Comment: I am using drupal 7

Comment: The better is to tag your question about Drupal version. Thanks :)

Comment: If you use Views 3, use the dev branch until it is stable. Using the alpha/beta/rc means you'll have bugs.

Answer (score 1):

It is really a personal decision on which one you should download. It is recommended to always download the one's in "Green". However views3 offers a significant improvement in the user interface and if you are just starting out in views, this might be a better choice.

A good article on choosing modules http://drupalwatchdog.com/1/1/module-selection-in-the-wild

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 7, there's now an RC (Release candidate).
However, I still think that for D7 modules before the first release, the -dev version is usually your best bet. This is the case with Views as well.